# Link back to original language from Google-translated web page

Tags: php, google-translate

I have a client's site where we provide links to Google Translate via flag icons. I would like to provide a link back to the original language (English) from the translated result.

You can see what I've got so far in action on the top-right of any page at [tesselaar.com](http://tesselaar.com)

If you click one of the flags, the page gets translated and the flag icons are replaced with an English version. I would like this flag to link back, but as you can see it doesn't because Google Translate is rewriting the URL I give it. Does anyone know how to get around this?

Here's my code:

```
<?php

echo "<ul class=\"breadcrumb pull-right\">\n";

if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "translate.google") !== false) { // page has been translated

  if (empty($_SESSION['return_url'])) $_SESSION['return_url'] = "tesselaar.com";

  echo "<li>View page in English:</li>\n";
  echo "<li><a target=\"_top\" href=\"http://" . $_SESSION['return_url'] . "\"><img src=\"/assets/img/flags/gb.gif\" width=\"16\" height=\"11\" title=\"English\" alt=\"English\"></a></li>\n";

} else { // regular site (not translated)

  $_SESSION['return_url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

  echo "<li>Translate this page:</li>\n";
  echo "<li><a href=\"http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=fr&u=tesselaar.com". $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "\"><img src=\"/assets/img/flags/fr.gif\" width=\"16\" height=\"11\" alt=\"French\"></a></li>\n";
  echo "<li><a href=\"http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=de&u=tesselaar.com". $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "\"><img src=\"/assets/img/flags/de.gif\" width=\"16\" height=\"11\" alt=\"German\"></a></li>\n";
  echo "<li><a href=\"http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=nl&u=tesselaar.com". $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "\"><img src=\"/assets/img/flags/nl.gif\" width=\"16\" height=\"11\" alt=\"Dutch\"></a></li>\n";
  echo "<li><a href=\"http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=es&u=tesselaar.com". $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "\"><img src=\"/assets/img/flags/es.gif\" width=\"16\" height=\"11\" alt=\"Spanish\"></a></li>\n";
  echo "<li><a href=\"http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=el&u=tesselaar.com". $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "\"><img src=\"/assets/img/flags/gr.gif\" width=\"16\" height=\"11\" alt=\"Greek\"></a></li>\n";

}

echo "</ul>\n\n";

?>
```

EDIT: Things I've tried, without success, since posting:

- Wrapping various things in a "notranslate" span.
- Using jQuery to try to rewrite the "link back" URL.
- Using jQuery to intercept the "link back" click and rewrite the parent frame.

Comment: Just in case anyone looks at the site & wonders about the discrepancy: After trying various jQuery solutions (none of which work), I've given up for now & have disabled the flag & return link.

Answer (score 2):

So i was able to solve your problem with jQuery. This is what I did:

```
<!-- inside your <head></head -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- inside your <body></body> -->
<?php $requestUri = str_replace('untranslate', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>
<ul class="breadcrumb pull-right">
    <?php if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "translate.google") !== false && !isset($_GET['untranslate'])) : ?>
        <li class="notranslate">View page in English:</li>
        <li>
            <a class="untranslate" href="#">
                <img src="/assets/img/flags/gb.gif" width="16" height="11" alt="English" />
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php $uri = "http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&u=" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>
        <li>Translate this page:</li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $uri . $requestUri ?>&tl=fr"><img src="/assets/img/flags/fr.gif" width="16" height="11" alt="French" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $uri . $requestUri ?>&tl=de"><img src="/assets/img/flags/ed.gif" width="16" height="11" alt="German" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $uri . $requestUri ?>&tl=nl"><img src="/assets/img/flags/nl.gif" width="16" height="11" alt="Dutch" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $uri . $requestUri ?>&tl=es"><img src="/assets/img/flags/es.gif" width="16" height="11" alt="Spanish" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $uri . $requestUri ?>&tl=el"><img src="/assets/img/flags/gr.gif" width="16" height="11" alt="Greek" /></a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>

<!-- right before your </body> or remove <script></script> and place in different js file -->
<script>
    $('.untranslate').click(function() {
        window.top.location = 'http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $requestUri ?>?untranslate';
    });
</script>
```

So basically there is a link without a url with the class `.untranslate` and then jQuery waits for that to be clicked. Once it's clicked it will redirect the page to the original page untranslated version of your site. Also it passes a get parameter called `untranslate` because the redirect passes the translate.google HTTP_REFERER.